# Force bluetooth permission request dialog always use landscape mode

Tags: android, bluetooth, orientation

In my own app I call bluetooth function , and I want to the bluetooth permission request dialog displayed in landscape mode.

I know how to force an Android activity to always use landscape mode and I have achieved this effect. But the bluetooth permission request dialog comes from system application. So how to control its orientation?

[image: I want the dialog landscape too]

Answer (score 0):

try to write the same code in onconfigurationchanged() method. When u change the orientation activity will came into this method & not to onCreate() method. & check now it will give u current result.

```
@Override
public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
    super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);

    if(newConfig.orientation == Configuration.ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE)
        Log.i("orientation", "Orientation changed to: Landscape");
    else
        Log.i("orientation", "Orientation changed to: Portrait");
}
```

Comment: Maybe you misunderstand my intention. The host app is already set  landscape mode and will hold this status. I just want to the bluetooth permission request dialog also display as landscape mode. But the dialog comes from system application, not mine.